# Optimal Subnet Configuration for a CI/CD with BeanStalk, GitHub, CodePipeline and Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, github, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-codepipeline

I am planning to create a **CI/CD configuration** **inside a VPC** which involves *AWS BeanStalk* (Host Environment), *GitHub* (Code Repository), *CodePipeline*, *Jenkins* (Code Build). The application located in the *GitHub* repository is supposed to run inside the *BeanStalk* environment, while any change to the *GitHub* repo should be reflected from the frontend.

I created a VPC with **2 public and private subnets each**. And I have provisioned a *BeanStalk* environment with *NodeJS* platform (the application is NodeJS). Then I am configuring the *CodePipeline*, in which Add Source stage, I have successfully managed to connect to the *GitHub* repo. Now, I am at the Code Build stage which I want to add a *Jenkins* which runs in an *EC2* instance. Therefore I am provisioning an *EC2* instance which I plan to install *Jenkins* and then mention it in the Code Build stage.

However, I am not sure **which subnet** the ***Jenkins EC2 instance*** should be. **Public or private**?

Comment: You can put it in public, just to check if your CP works as intended. Once you know that CP works correctly, you can think how to move it to private subnet. In private subnet it will be more secure, but setting it up can require some exercise, as by default, there is no access to internet in private subnets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For more secure architecture host jenkins in a private subnet and setup AWS codepipeline to use VPC endpoints,  With VPC endpoints, no public IP addresses are required and traffic between the VPC and CodePipeline does not leave the Amazon network.